# Binding Command doesn't respond at all

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding, navigation, command

I Already used `TapGestureRecognizer` and bind them to certain command and that command works fine...

Here is example:

IrrigNetPage.xaml (view)

```
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TabTappedCommand}" CommandParameter="map"/>
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

<Grid IsVisible="{Binding IsGridHeaderVisible}">
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HideListOnTapCommand}"/>
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
</Grid>
```

IrrigNetPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class IrrigNetPage : ContentPage
{
    public IrrigNetPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new IrrigNetViewModel();
    }
}
```

IrrigNetViewModel.cs

```cs
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class IrrigNetViewModel : PopupPage
{
    public ICommand TabTappedCommand { get; }
    public ICommand HideListOnTapCommand { get; }
    public ICommand ShowIrrigNetDetailPageCommand { get; }

    public IrrigNetViewModel()
    {
        TabTappedCommand = new Command((tabName) => OnTapClicked(tabName.ToString()));
        HideListOnTapCommand = new Command(HideListOnTap);
        ShowIrrigNetDetailPageCommand = new Command(ShowDetailPage);

    private void ShowDetailPage()
    {
        Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new IrrigNetDetailsPage());
    }

    private void HideListOnTap()
    {
        IsListVisible = !IsListVisible;
    }

    private void OnTapClicked(string tabName)
    {

        if (tabName == "location")
        {
....
```

So I done everzthing on the same way for TabTappedCommand and HideListOnTapCommand as for ShowIrrigNetDetailPageCommand but for some reason nothing happen when i tap on TapGestureRecognizer.
I tried to debug, but I don't get any exception or error... Just nothing happend...

I instaled Rg.Plugins.Popup, because IrrigNetDetailsPage.xaml is `<pages:PopupPage mlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
...`

IrrigNetDetailsPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class IrrigNetDetailsPage : PopupPage
{
    public IrrigNetDetailsPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new IrrigNetDetailsViewModel();
    }
}
```

IrrigNetPage.xaml binding (which not working)

```
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowIrrigNetDetailPageCommand}"/>
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>
```

So, I done everything on the same way as for `TabTappedCommand` and `HideListOnTapCommand`, but obvious I missing something...

Comment: do your layouts really have no content other than a gesture recognizer?

Comment: Just to be clear, did you put a breakpoint in `HideListOnTap` and it wasn't hit? Or did you just not see any errors not the functionality you expected?

Comment: @Jason ofcourse they have content. I just posted sample code parts where I binding tapGestureRecognizer to command etc what is imported. (I didn't post parts of code where I defined margines, panding, texts etc... :D)

Comment: @Knoop `HideListOnTap` is example of what working fine...My problem is `ShowDetailPage`. :D
I set breakpoint in `ShowDetailPage` and it's not hit...

Comment: TabTappedCommand has an argument, so it should be definied as an ICommand<string>

Comment: @Jason `TabTappedCommand` works fine. Problem is `ShowDetailPage`...
Point is that I want to navigate from `IrrigNetPage` to `IrrigNetDetailsPage` when I tap frame on IrrigNetPage.

Comment: If ShowDetailPage is the problem, why didn't you post the XAML for it?

Comment: @Jason `ShowDetailPage` is a method which should navigate from `IrrigNetPage` to `IrrigNetDetailsPage`.

Comment: Yeah it seems like we're missing some code. You talk about navigation in the command but all the command does in the code you've provided is `IsListVisible = !IsListVisible;`. Also since you're question seems to be about the command not being fired I would advise to start with a breakpoint in `HideListOnTap` to see if it's firing. At this point it seems you're working under assumptions that don't have to be correct (navigation isn't working because the command is not firing).

Comment: @Knoop Ofc I can edit question and post some more code but everything is here... Binding, proporties, command, s everything from view, viewmodel (model is still not iportant for this question)... Ofc I set breakpoint in `HideListOnTap` and it's fired. 
Yup "navigation isn't working because the command is not firing". :D

Answer (score 0):

When you are navigating in a method, it needs to be async. So your method would look like this:

```
private async void ShowDetailPage()
    {
        Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new IrrigNetDetailsPage());
    }
```